# Fine level messages aren't showing

Tags: java, logging

My .FINE log messages aren't showing in the output.

```
  public void playerCoinUpdate(Player player, Coin coin, GameEngine engine)
   {
       String update = String.format(player.getPlayerName() +" coin " + coin.getNumber() + "flipped to " + coin.getFace() + "\n");  
      // intermediate results logged at Level.FINE
      logger.log(Level.FINE, update);
   }

It should output a message to the console.
```

Comment: Well, have you checked how your logger is configured? Also, lacking your question: Environment (Java SE, Java EE), minimal reproducible example, your effort so far.

Answer (score 0):

The message will not show if your logger level is higher than the message level. This can be fixed by changing the logger level:

`logger.setLevel(level.FINE);`

This will now log messages that are level FINE and above. So levels FINER and FINEST will be ignored. Alternatively, you could allow all messages to be logged by using this:

`logger.setLevel(level.ALL);`

The Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/class-use/Level.html) has other useful information regarding logging.

Comment: If the answer satisfies your requirements, click the check symbol to accept it. That way we get to know that your query has been solved.